# python IF statement assignment

Tags: python

so i want to create an input, that gets the user's age, AND tells him if whether or not he can eat pizza according to his age.
the minimum age to eat pizza in the state of 'booliland' is 25.
so this is what i wrote.

```
pizza_age = 25
user_age = int(input("what is your age?"))
if user_age < 25:
    print("your are now allowed to eat pizza yet.. please wait another" + pizza_age % user_age + "years until u can eat pizza")
```

now, the print line is supposed (according to my "knowledge" (HAHAHA), to calculate how many years he has to wait until he can eat pizza, according to the age the user stated in the input.

could someone guide me without telling me the answer?
thank you :D

Comment: This is just grade school math -- if you're 6 years old, how many years is it until you're 16?  Is it `16 - 6 = 10` or `16 % 6 = 4`?

Comment: 1. Your calculation should be `pizza_age - user_age`. 2. Separate the expressions in the `print()` call with commas, not plus signs: `print("you are not allowed to eat pizza yet.. please wait another", pizza_age - user_age, "years until you can eat pizza")`

Answer (score 0):

You simply have write the wrong symbol. It's:

```
pizza_age - user_age
```

and not

```
pizza_age % user_age
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments & other answer you need to subtraction. Moreover, I am just suggesting to use `str()` to concatenate your subtraction in resulting string:

```
pizza_age = 25
user_age = int(input("what is your age?"))
if user_age < 25:
    print("your are now allowed to eat pizza yet.. please wait another " + str(pizza_age-user_age)+ " years until u can eat pizza")
```